# Mongoose Schema for Notes and Versions

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to create a schema in mongoose like this

A user can create a new note by giving a title and a content
A user can update the note which will create a new version of the note
Each version of the note can query separately.

I work with Mysql and new to MongoDB, Please suggest me a schema and how do I insert a new note, update the node?

Answer (score 1):

### Background

Firstly, I think it would be worth you reading about document based databases, and how MongoDB implements this. These are good reads:

https://www.ibmbpnetwork.com/linux-blog/mongodb-architecture

https://medium.com/chingu/an-overview-of-mongodb-mongoose-b980858a8994

### Schema

Regarding your question, there could be many answers to this, especially:

> how do I insert a new note, update the node?

I would have your `user` schema link to the schema of a `note`, something like this:

```
var notesSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title:       String,
  description: String,
  user:        [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
  created_at:  { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  updated_at:  { type: Date, default: Date.now }
  ... 
  ...
});
```

Where your user schema would be defined elsewhere (ill assume you can do this?). It may also be useful to read 'subdocuments' and see if that better fits your model.

**Note:** add what fields you need, all fields are *optional* by default, probably useful for `description` & `title`.

Im not sure how big you expect your notes to be, but remember

> the only limitation is that of the 16MB maximum document size

So how you store this, I'll let you decide.

To insert new notes, you'll need to make a call to your API, again this is rather vague and can be done many ways depending on your design.

Mongoose can insert document, and update documents quite easily.

Comment: Hi, 
I want to have multiple versions of the note and would want to fetch the latest note  or on the basis of the version.

Here is the schema

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/amirsaleem-kn/36d943dfc07f87802bfb4d648eccc2c2/raw/f25b4f86bfa2bde8cc2f1112cec11e0ee51a4caa/tempSchema

Comment: I am from a MySQL background, I just want to do it for now and then will give mongodb a read. As I have a time constraint, could you please provide me the exact code.

I want :
one to many relationship  between a user and notes
one to many relationship between notes and its versions

At a particular time, if no versionId is available, latest version is fetched, if versionId is available, that version of note is fetched